# What will cause a SecurityErrorEvent?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, security, flash-builder, firewall

I'm executing the following command:

```
var chatRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test.com/videophonetest/scripts/get_put_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID);
                chatLoader = new URLLoader(chatRequest);
                configureListenersChatLoader(chatLoader);
                chatLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
                chatLoader.load(chatRequest);
```

`configureListenersChatLoader(chatLoader)` and friends looks like:

```
private function configureListenersDeleteLoader(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
                dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandlerDeleteLoader);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            }


            private function completeHandlerChatLoader(event:Event):void {              
                writeText("Completed Connection!");
                var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(chatLoader.data);
                writeText("Your ID: " + myID);
                theirID = urlVariables.peerID;
                writeText("Their ID: " + theirID);          
            }
            private function completeHandlerDeleteLoader(event:Event):void {                
                writeText("Deletion Complete!");
                var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(deleteLoader.data);
                writeText("Deleted: " + urlVariables.deleted);
                writeText("Getting New Chat...");
                initNewChatSession();               
            }

            private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
                writeText("openHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
                writeText("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
            }

            private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
                writeText("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
                writeText("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
                writeText("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
            }
```

The command works on my computer but when I try it on my roommates computer it returns an error:

```
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0 responseURL=null]

securityErrorHandler: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]
```

Any reason why this might be happening? It works on some computers but not others. Firewalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to allow the location of the file on your friends' computer in this settings manager:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html